# How does one dispose of a field

Tags: c#, idisposable

I recently started using code analyzer and OOOO! boy do i have a lot of violations lol.
most are of iDisposable i have been doing my research and so far i have managed to dispose of a few.
however i think i have exhausted the tiny bit of smarts i got so help anyone.

public partial class Form1 : Form already implements the idisposable method i just don't know in what way i should use it in this case.

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form 

   {

     private readonly Label CompPany = new Label();

    private readonly SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = 
    new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en- 
    US"));

   }
```

i need to know how to dispose of this kind of field

Comment: A `Form` already implements `IDisposable`. All you need to do is override [Dispose(bool)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) and call `_recognizer.Dispose()` if disposing is `true`.

Comment: please can you show me a code example? pleaseeee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Form already implements IDisposable. All you need to do is override Dispose(bool) and call _recognizer.Dispose() if disposing is true:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    private readonly SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = 
        new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _recognizer.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

By this, whenever the form is disposed, also the created SpeechRecognitionEngine  will be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

The `Dipose` method is exposed by the `IDisposable` interface, only objects that implement this interface will have that method. Use this method to close or release unmanaged resources such as files, streams, and handles held by an instance of the class that implements this interface. By convention, this method is used for all tasks associated with freeing resources held by an object, or preparing an object for reuse. `SpeechRecognitionEngine` implements `IDisposable` then it has the `Dispose` method. See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose?view=netframework-4.8) for more info. If instead you're trying to also dispose of the `Form` then it already implements `IDisposable`, just override it like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    private readonly SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = 
        new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

    protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _recognizer.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: SpeechRecognitionEngine implements IDisposable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: so pretty much i will need to add these code to a separate class and implement to that class the idisposable ?

Comment: Any class you want to be explicitly disposable (since everything is disposable from the GC perspective) must implement (inherit) the `IDisposable` interface. The docs is full of examples. Remember to check that out. But don't hesitate to ask anything.

Comment: i now understand how this works, but i still get shown the idisposable warning.

Comment: What warning? Share the text.

Comment: @Javier Silva Ortíz.i solved it thanks. i have another problem but i cant post it here i think its with an image that i load into my form i want to update that image by deleting it and saving the new image in its place but it keeps saying the image is being used. i will link to the code in  a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828752/replace-image-with-new-image