# Replace image with new image

Tags: c#, image

when i try to delete the image i get this error i tried to dispose of the picture box but that doesn't seem to work.

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users*******\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2019\Project****************\dbo\DBImages\Bolgheri Sassicaia.jpg'
>   because it is being used by another process.'

the image i load from this folder, i want to delete it and then add another picture with the same name.
pretty much i want to update the image.

This is where i load the image to the picture box

```
if (imagepathtext.TextLength > 0)
{
    image1 = Image.FromFile(imagepathtext.Text);
    drinkImageView.Image = image1;
}
```

This is where i try to replace the image.

```
      private void UpdatebtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (imagepath.TextLength > 9)
        {

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you also trying to 
            update image?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                image1.Dispose();
                System.IO.File.Delete(imagepathtext.Text);
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out after long trials and error.
We have to dispose of the image before loading the new image.
like so

```
    private void BrowseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrinkView.Image.Dispose();
        var imagePath = image.BROWSEIMAGE();
        if (imagePath.Length > 10)
        {
            DrinkView.Image = new Bitmap(imagePath);
            imagepath.Text = imagePath;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose `image1` object to close file handle. This is actual object keeping handle to your file.

Before this call

```
System.IO.File.Delete(imagepathtext.Text);
```

make sure to dispose `image1` object

```
image1.Dispose();
```

Comment: please see where i add the dispose in edited code above.

Comment: After `drinkImageView.Dispose();` also do `drinkImageView.Image.Dispose();`. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: it is still being used. i dont know i cant seem to find what is using the file i mean if i try to delete after i load the image in the first method to view, it deletes fine.

Comment: the image is saved in my project folder could that be the reason the image is still being used?

Comment: @RickHamton Are you sure you are not opening this file from another place in your application?

Comment: no i am not the image opens on this form which is the only active form

Comment: i load the path of the file from my database to a  textbox then i use that text as the image1

Comment: i have other forms that will eventually use the image but non of these form are active as i have not done a call to them as yet

Comment: is it possible to tell what is using the image from the exception?

Comment: so i did some test i have a picturebox called locationsview, one of my bar image got deleted and i notice when it did not find the bar image it still loaded the drink image that is in use. so it seem the answer is yes there is something else that is using the image i now need to find out how where in my code i went wrong.